# On the usage of "according to"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is it ok to use "according to" in the following way?

> Our firm have different solution programs according to customers' needs or expectations.
>
> The school provides variety of books according to the student's age and
>   education level.

Comment: Having you looked up "according to" in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be "our firm **has**", "needs **and** expectations", "**a** variety of books", and "**educational** level" (or "level of education").  Otherwise your use of "according to" is fine.

However, if you want to get into nuance, "according to" is more like "consistent with" than "at the level of".  So while your use of "according to" in the first sentence is good, in the second sentence, "based on" or "appropriate to/for" might be better.

> The school provides a variety of books based on each student's age and level of education.
>
> The school provides a variety of books appropriate to the student's age and educational level.
>
> The school provides a variety of books appropriate for (different) students' ages and educational levels.

Comment: Thank you .This is what exactly I was wondering. I didn't want to change the focus of the question but I wonder if I can use the word accordingly in any way in the first sentence as "Our firm have different solution programs accordingly  customers' needs or expectations"

Comment: "Accordingly" is an adverb, so it can't modify the noun "programs" and is out of place.  You want to use an adjective or adjectival phrase.  Also, I didn't catch it before but "solution programs" is not natural English.  "Solutions" is sufficient.

Comment: @Mrt I edited my comment.  Please see my answer above.

Comment: As a  last question : how about this sentence : "Our firm have different solutions customers' needs accordingly. "

Comment: Again, as an adverb, "accordingly" doesn't correctly modify the noun "needs".  Also, again, it should be "our firm has" not "our firm have" (yes, I understand there's a rule about using plurals with collective nouns but that's probably best posted as a separate question)

Comment: I'm sure if I really try I can find a way to work "accordingly" in this sentence, but it wouldn't sound as good as something like, "Our firm has solutions to meet each customer's needs and expectations".

Comment: ok..I don't think it is necessary to push it  too much if you think it would not sound  better..I liked your sentence but it seems like when I use " according to" , there are already readily available solutions , maybe tested before, in the first sentence, at least this is what I tried to say.. another similar example  " The institution provides/offers a variety of courses according to every prospect student's needs" , whereas in your sentence as if  the firm promises to commit to meet the needs..It is subtle difference I discern.I can be wrong though.

Comment: In advertising, it's not uncommon to make promises you hope you can keep  :)

Answer (score 0):

May I also suggest the following: **in accordance with**; synonyms include: *as per* - *be duly executed* (legal) - *[pursuant to](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/pursuant)* (legal)

> Always use medicines in accordance with the manufacturer's instructions.
>    To be in accordance with the law, you must pay your taxes.

Merriam-Webster defines it

> [in accordance with](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20accordance%20with)
>   : agreement, conformity
>   : the act of granting

It is a rather high brow, and formal  expression, suitable for business and legal environments.